# How to get the pdf version of spring security 3.2.x?

Tags: spring, security, pdf

I can get the html version here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/

However, anyone knows how to get the pdf version ?

Thanks!

Comment: ...use a PDF printer?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [docs.gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/docs/docs.gradle) in the github repository of Spring Security, only `reference/htmlsingle` exists.

Perhaps you could check out the code and add the corresponding PDF support in that file and perform the build on your own.

Comment: It's inconvenient. It's better if spring.io can provide it for developers to download directly.